# Spring MVC Validating a form that is encoded with encType="multipart/form-data"

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, enctype

I have a **Spring MVC** application that uses **encType="multipart/form-data"**. The form is a user registration form with an image among other fields e.g. username, first name ,last name, dob ect. The form is then submitted to Controller which calls validation by the **@InitBinder** annotation.

When the file is posted to the class that handles the validation all the values are **NULL**. I read this will happen because of the  **encType="multipart/form-data"** in the **`<form>`** tag. I am also using this bean definition in the applicationcontext.xml :

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="157286400" />
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="5242880"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf-8"/>
</bean>
```

Can someone give me an example on how i can extract the values from this file and validate them. I am not sure how i can receive the data in the validator class and process its contents.

**Validation Class**

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.crimetrack.business.Citizens;


@Component
public class CitizenRegistrationValidation implements Validator{

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;


    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

        return Citizens.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {


            Citizens citizens = (Citizens)target;   

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    String user_request =  request.getParameter("user_request");
    String photo = request.getParameter("photo");   


    logger.info("Thee request param for photo is :"+ photo);
    logger.info("About to validate citizen");
    logger.info("The user request was " + user_request);

    if (!user_request.equals("New")){
        if (user_request.equals("Save") || user_request.equals("update")){

                if(citizens.getSocialSecurityNumber() == 0){

                    errors.rejectValue("socialSecurityNumber", "socialSecurityNumber.required");

                }



                if (citizens.getCitizenTypeId() == 1){

                    errors.rejectValue("citizenTypeId", "citizenTypeId.required");
                }

                if(citizens.getfName() == null){

                    errors.rejectValue("fName", "fName.required");
                }

                if (citizens.getlName() == null){

                    errors.rejectValue("lName", "lName.required");
                }

                if (citizens.getDob() == null){

                    errors.rejectValue("dob", "dob.required");
                }
```

Comment: One would expect it to be as simple as described in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-resolver.

Comment: How is this question different from [your question earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504442/springmvc-and-enctype-multipart-form-data)?

Comment: It does not say anything about accessing elements within the file e.g. if you post a button with a value how are you going to access the value with that item. If you use request.getParameter() NULL is returned

Comment: @parsifal I am not getting a proper response on the question i asked earlier so i though maybe i should rephrase it and ask again.

Comment: @dev_darin - it's generally considered better etiquette to modify your old question to provide the information requested. If you feel that this is a better question, you could delete the old one.

Comment: @parsifal ok thanks i will delete the repeated question